# Detecting when floating action button is hidden

Tags: android, callback, overriding, visibility, floating-action-button

I have a scrolling activity, and I want to be notified when the floating action button is being hidden.
In order to do so, I created `MyFab` which extends `FloatingActionButton` and an interface (to use as a callback) to call when the floating action button is being hidden, but I can't quite figure out what method is being called when I scroll and the floating action button disappears (I want to override the method, so I can call super and the callback that is implemented in the activity)

The interface:

```
public interface OnAppearanceChangedListener {
    void onAppearanceChanged(int alpha);
}
```

My Floating Action Button:

```
public class MyFloatingActionButton extends FloatingActionButton {
    private OnAppearanceChangedListener mListener;

    public void setListener(OnAppearanceChangedListener mListener){
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }
    /*insert code here to call mListener.onAppearanceChanged(),
      probably by overriding some method */
}
```

The activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnAppearanceChangedListener {
    @Override
    public void onAppearanceChanged(boolean visible) {
        // I want this function to be called when Floating Action Button hide/show state is changed
    }
}
```

--edit--
figured it out. `animate()` was the function I was looking for. It is being called to animate the floating action button shrinking action (what I was referring to as hiding)

Comment: Can you please add the code for more clarification?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite ambiguous but if what you are looking for is to animate (hide) the fab on scroll you might want to refer to this [tutorial](http://thetechnocafe.com/how-to-hide-floating-action-button-on-when-scrolling-in-recycler-view/).  Otherwise explain your post to gain more help in community.

Cheers